# Can I run OWIN Middleware in an older MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, owin

We are specifically trying to run SignalR in an older MVC3 application. We went down to v1.2 and it still throws an obsolete exception on the MapConnection method and wants to use AppBuild.MapConnection instead.

Is there a way to run SignalR in Owin in an older MVC3 application?
It need  not be SignalR really, any Owin middleware will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately there is no out of the box method that can  provide Owin for MVC 3,
however there are some frameworks which can help you out:
[NaNcy](http://nancyfx.org/) , [Simple Web](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Web)

hope they will help you to achieve what oyu wanted :)

BR